# How can I merge different values as an array on own key

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays included same keys but, values can be different.
I have arrays included same keys but, values can be different.

my arrays:

```
$arr1 = json_decode('{

"Chain": "Monaco Chain",

"Style": "Monaco Swarovski",

"Gauge": "9.50 mm",

"Length": "30.00",

"Color": "YELLOW",

"Karat": "21",

"Lock": "Long",

"2 Tone": "Yes",

"Alternate": "Yes"

}', true);

$arr2 = json_decode('{

"Chain": "Monaco Chain",

"Style": "Monaco Swarovski",

"Gauge": "9.50 mm",

"Length": "30.00",

"Color": "GREEN",

"Karat": "21",

"Lock": "Long",

"2 Tone": "Yes",

"Alternate": "Yes"

}', true);

$arr3 = json_decode('{

"Chain": "Monaco Chain",

"Style": "Monaco Swarovski",

"Gauge": "9.50 mm",

"Length": "30.00",

"Color": "YELLOW",

"Karat": "21",

"Lock": "Long",

"2 Tone": "No",

"Alternate": "Yes"

}', true);

$arr4 = json_decode('{

"Chain": "Monaco Chain",

"Style": "Monaco Swarovski",

"Gauge": "9.50 mm",

"Length": "300.00",

"Color": "YELLOW",

"Karat": "21",

"Lock": "Long",

"2 Tone": "Yes",

"Alternate": "Yes"

}', true)
```

I have to merge different values as an array and keep them in their own key, so I should get this output:

```
'{

"Chain": "Monaco Chain",

"Style": "Monaco Swarovski",

"Gauge": "9.50 mm",

"Length": ["30.00", "300.00"],

"Color": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"],

"Karat": "21",

"Lock": "Long",

"2 Tone": ["Yes", "No"],

"Alternate": "Yes"

}'
```

Note: Please don't care the jsons.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Thanks for your response @RakeshJakhar, I'm trying build a new array like I needed.

Comment: How many arrays you have? are you export them from a database or what? Because I know the solution. But it is only for two arrays. If you tell me how do you create those array, maybe I can provide you some better answare :)

Comment: Thank you @NemanjaJeremic, I have approximately 10k arrays, I want to just merge same keys.

Comment: and there is no so many value differences.

Comment: can you provide a solution how do you export them from the database? because then ill can help you better. You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php
But to make you a better solution. I need to know how you export them from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I think the issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

```php
function key_concat(...$arrays) {
    if (count($arrays) == 1) return $arrays[0];
    $temp = array_shift($arrays);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrays); $i++) {
        foreach($arrays[$i] as $key => $value) {
            if ((is_string($temp[$key]) && trim($temp[$key]) != trim($arrays[$i][$key])) ||
                (is_array($temp[$key]) && array_search($arrays[$i][$key], $temp[$key]) === false)
            ) {
                if (is_string($temp[$key])) {
                    $temp[$key] = Array($temp[$key], $arrays[$i][$key]);
                } else if (is_array($temp[$key])) {
                    $temp[$key][] = $arrays[$i][$key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $temp;
}
print_r(key_concat($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4, $arr5));
```